# Float text against image without wrapping underneath

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph of text against a floated image; is there a way to get the text to stay against the border formed by the side of the image, but not go underneath it when the text flows past the bottom of the image?

CSS:

```css
.textChunk {
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}

.leftPic {
  max-width: 35%;
  max-height: 35%;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="textChunk">
    <img class="leftPic" src="images/joshFace.png">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting `overflow: auto` to the paragraph:

```
.textChunk p { overflow: auto; }
```

This causes a new block formatting context to be created and the left edge of the block will not go beyond the edge of the float (that  is, wrap around).

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/tPC4z/

Answer (score 0):

You will try this method. add the overflow:hidden for p element:

```
p{overflow: hidden;zoom:1;}
```

you can click [here](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/how-to-fix-wrapping-text-around-floated-elements) to know any more.

Answer (score -1):

Align the image left with html:

```
.textChunk {
  font-family: 'Special Elite', cursive;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.leftPic {
  max-width: 35%;
  max-height: 35%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```
<div class="textChunk">
    // align="left" added
    <img class="leftPic" src="images/joshFace.png" align="left">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
```